# Doesn't show any output in this web-API

Tags: php, rest, curl, web, asp.net-web-api

Can someone help me to understand how to do this API thing? The problem is, it doesn't display an output. Then, I have learned that the `GET` is not really needed(can be there or not) to be part of the code, but in this case, when I am deleting the `GET` I am getting an error output. This [link](https://support.dudamobile.com/API/REST-Resources/Analytics) is what I need to do...(please see the link)

So far, I have this code...

```
<?php
$data = '';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'GET https://api.dudamobile.com/api/analytics/site/{site_name}?from=2015-01-12&result=activities');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{username}:{password}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',       
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))                                                                       
);   
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($output);
?>
```

Comment: `GET https://...` is not a valid URL. I suspect the error message in "when I am deleting the GET I am getting an error output" is relevant, so it'd be nice if you'd tell us what it was.

Comment: `{"error_code":"ResourceNotExist","message":"Site with alias '{siename}' doesn't exist"}` -- this is the error @ceejayoz

Comment: That's an error from the API you're using, not from PHP/cURL. Your cURL code is fine (if you get rid of the `GET` in the `CURLOPT_URL`). Ask the people who made the API for help - it looks like you've probably just got the wrong sitename in your request.